# Javascript: Trouble with JSFiddle - Simple onclick event to output String does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I have this super simple onclick event:

Click the button to trigger a function that will output "Hello World" in a p element with id="demo".

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>
```

Works fine here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick

Works fine when I try it on my machine.

But it does not work on JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6nrh408f/

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Option `No wrap - in - <head>` or `No wrap - in - <body>` Save yourself some hassle and consider [unobtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scope issue. Assign this function to global variable this way:

```
myFunction = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/6nrh408f/1/

Answer (score 0):

Because in the fiddle you are defining the function inside the `onload` function instead of the `head`. So `myFunction` scope is not global and not accessible/defined when used in the `onclick` handler.

Simply change the top left select box to **No wrap - in ...** instead of **onLoad**.

Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nrh408f/2/) updated.